# Overleaf LaTeX: Bunch of errors when checking word count

Tags: latex, word-count, xelatex

I am currently using Overleaf to write a report but encountered errors when I click word count in the menu:

```
!!! Encountered } without corresponding {. !!!
!!! Encountered \end without corresponding \begin !!!
!!! Reached end of file while waiting for }. !!!
!!! Reached end of file while waiting for \end. !!!
!!! Environment ended while waiting for nd{document}. !!!
```

It appears that these two lines I added to change the format of the chapter title are causing the errors but I'm not sure why this occurs.

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\bfseries}{}{10pt}{\Huge\thechapter.\quad}
```